# Convert JSON to Cursor

Tags: android, json, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I have some data in JSON format that I'd like to convert into a cursor so it can be returned by a content provider. What's the best way to go about this?

I considered using a `MatrixCursor` but my content provider needs to return type `Cursor`, not `MatrixCursor`.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: pist what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MatrixCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) extends [`AbstractCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html), `AbstractCursor` implements [`CrossProcessCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CrossProcessCursor.html), and `CrossProcessCursor` implements [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html). So you can use `MatrixCursor` in your content provider.

But note that even you can put a `byte[]` array into `MatrixCursor`, however [`Cursor.getBlob()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getBlob(int)) returns wrong value *in older APIs*. There was an issue (it was fixed). I couldn't remember or find the link to the issue but you can easily test it on emulators  :-)  Or here is a related question: [Passing binary blob through a content provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034575/passing-binary-blob-through-a-content-provider).